# Allocate released floating IP in openstack

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

How do I allocate Floating IP to a tenant after the tenant releases it from the project in openstack?

Suppose I want IP 10.10.90.95, how can I add this specific IP to my pool available list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To claim a *specific* floating-ip for a tenant, you can run the following neutron command. Note that this will succeed only if that IP address is not already claimed by some other tenant:

```
neutron floatingip-create --floating-ip-address 10.10.90.95 ext-net
```

Above assumes that your external network is named "ext-net" and the IP address you are trying to allocate is 10.10.90.95.

Comment: let me try this

Comment: Hi Praveen, this will work when I have the IP in my tenant and wont work if got released back to the pool.

Comment: Once that IP gets assigned to some other tenant/project, it is not possible to claim it back for your project anymore. If that IP is still available in the pool, you can claim it using the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Once floating IP is released, it gets automatically added to the available floating ip pool.

Use:

> nova floating-ip-associate < instance-id > < floating-ip >

to associate specific floating-ip to the instance.

Comment: This is true when IP is disassociated from VM. I released it from my project.